# What's the reason for the ordering of for statements in a nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) describes how to use list comprehensions to flatten a nested structure, like so:

`[leaf for tree in forest for leaf in tree]`

As [John Mee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75033/john-mee) mentions in the comments, this would be clearer if the order of the `for` statements was reversed, like so:

`[leaf for leaf in tree for tree in forest]`

Why are for loops in Python's list comprehensions interpreted in this order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to mimic nested `for` loops.

```
[x for y in z for x in y]
```

is organized in the same order as

```
for y in z:
    for x in y:
        yield x
```

This is mentioned in [PEP 202 - List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#bdfl-pronouncements)

> The form `[... for x... for y...]` nests, with the last index varying fastest, just like nested for loops.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first one is better mapping to the for loop code it represented

```
[leaf *for tree in forest for leaf in tree*]
                      |
                      V
            for tree in forest:
                for leaf in tree:
                      |
                      V
               expected result
```

while the second one is in this sense not valid

```
[leaf *for leaf in tree for tree in forest*]
                      |
                      V
            for leaf in tree:
                for tree in forest: 
                      |
                      V
                     ???
```